# Read fixed size of bytes of inputSream

Tags: java, android, sockets, bitmap, inputstream

We are working on a video streaming application ,
currently   we are able to capture video and process it frame by frame then send/receive data between two devices .

the problem is at the receiving side , as we are sending frames with fixed size so at the receiving side should also process them with a fixed size or he will not be able to get the frame .

Hope this diagrams clarify  the problem.

Transmitting process :
[image]

Code :

```
public void process(@NonNull Frame frame) {
            byte[] data = frame.getData();           
            frameWidth = frame.getSize().getWidth();
            frameHieght = frame.getSize().getHeight();
            YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, frame.getFormat(), frameWidth, frameHieght, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHieght), 25, out);
            final byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
            frameByteSize = bytes.length;

            OutputStream outputStream = StreamHandler.getOutputStream();
            if (out != null) {
             try {
                   outputStream.write(bytes, 0, frameByteSize);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                   }
    }
```

Reviving process :
[image]

Code :

```
public void run() {
        int read = 0;
        int hold = 0;
        int frameSize = StreamHandler.getFrameByteSize();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            if (SrtreamHandler != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = StreamHandler.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                    while (microPhoneActive) {
                        byte[] frame = new byte[frameSize];
                        read = bufferedInputStream.read(frame, 0, frame.length);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(frame, 0, frame.length);
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            final Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, -90);
                            frameEvent.onNewFrame(rotatedBitmap);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

currently the buffer reader is reading chunks of data with different sizes ,therefor the bitmap that get build will be as following : 
[image]

the black side of image have not been received yet because the buffered reader did not block and wait until all buffered have been filled.

Comment: You should collect the chuncks until you have a complete frame. That bytes come in in chuncks is pretty normal using tcp/ip.

Comment: You are doing nothing with the `read` integer. Start checking how much bytes are really read.

Comment: @greenapps when I keep reading until have complete frame , in most cases i will end up with a complete frame and some bytes of the next frame witch  will corrupt the next frame and all the frames to come after , is there a data structure that handle framing ? 
as for the read value  i've already read the data and it's less than the frame i've corrupted the  stream

Comment: You should not already read the bytes of the next frame of course. You should only read the bytes of one frame first. Collect chuncks until you have a frame. Use the link provided by Oleg.

Comment: @greenapps that is exactly my problem right now , i know that the use of inputStream.available() is useless , and read is blocking but not with fixed length

Comment: It is no problem. Everybody who does tcp/ip programming has to keep track of its 'frames'. You are #123456 who has to deal with it. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a false assumption that the frame size is fixed,

The logic was to get the first frame size provided by the camera then send it to the other side on a different  control Chanel then continue the rest of the stream relaying on that information ,
that would work if i was not doing a lossy compression  to the image

```
yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHieght), 25, out);
```

witch result to different frame sizes ,with help of @Oleg comment about this
 post [How to read all of Inputstream in Server Socket JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839172/how-to-read-all-of-inputstream-in-server-socket-java)

the code look like this ,
sending :

```
public void process(@NonNull Frame frame) {
            byte[] data = frame.getData();
                frameWidth = frame.getSize().getWidth();
                frameHieght = frame.getSize().getHeight();

                YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, frame.getFormat(), frameWidth, frameHieght, null);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHieght), 25, out);
                final byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
                frameByteSize = bytes.length;

                if (StreamHandler != null) {
                    OutputStream outputStream = StreamHandler.getOutputStream();
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {
                            byte firstByte = (byte) ((bytes.length & 0xff00) >> 8);
                            byte secondByte = (byte) (bytes.length & 0xFF);
                            outputStream.write(firstByte);
                            outputStream.write(secondByte);
                            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, frameByteSize);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

receiving :

```
public void run() {
        int read = 0;
        int hold = 0;
        int frameSize = StreamHandler.getFrameByteSize();
        try {
            if (StreamHandler != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = SrtreamHandler.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                    byte[] frameInfo = new byte[2];
                    while (microPhoneActive) {
                        frameInfo[0] = dataInputStream.readByte();
                        frameInfo[1] = dataInputStream.readByte();
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(frameInfo, 0, 2);
                        int bytesToRead = byteBuffer.getShort();
                        byte[] frame = new byte[bytesToRead];
                        dataInputStream.readFully(frame, 0, bytesToRead);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(frame, 0, frame.length);
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            final Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, -90);
                            frameEvent.onNewFrame(rotatedBitmap);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> currently the buffer reader is reading chunks of data with different sizes

Okay, what's wrong with that?

`read` doesn't always read all the data you asked for, for various reasons. You need to keep reading until you've read all the data you wanted to read.